# Кнопки у элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать? Что бы кнопки <<просмотр>> и <<добавить>>, появлялись при наведение на элемент и исчезали когда мышка не наведена?

```js
var IDimg = "-5tHiZACxbI",
  ImgYuoTube = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + IDimg + "/mqdefault.jpg";


const app = document.querySelector(".app");
const kn = document.createElement("input");
kn.type = "button";
kn.value = "Кнопка";
kn.onclick = function f() {
  go();
};

document.getElementById('elbed').appendChild(kn);

function go() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    const youtube = document.createElement("div");
    const title = document.createElement("div");
    youtube.className = "yo";
    youtube.innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='el'>Просмотор</a><a href='#' class='el1'>Добавить</a><img style='width: 130px;height: 90px' src='" + ImgYuoTube + "'>";
    youtube.setAttribute("youtub_clip", i);
    title.innerText = "Не понятное название ";
    title.className = "yo1";
    app.appendChild(youtube);
    youtube.appendChild(title);
    youtube.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log("ТЕСТ", i);
    });
  }

}
```

```css
.yo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.yo1 {
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  outline-width: 10px;
}

.el {
  position: absolute;
  color: deepskyblue;
  left: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.el1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: deepskyblue;
  left: 30px;
  top: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="elbed"></div>
<div class="app">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var IDimg = "-5tHiZACxbI",
  ImgYuoTube = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + IDimg + "/mqdefault.jpg";


const app = document.querySelector(".app");
const kn = document.createElement("input");
kn.type = "button";
kn.value = "Кнопка";
kn.onclick = function f() {
  go();
};

document.getElementById('elbed').appendChild(kn);

function go() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    const youtube = document.createElement("div");
    const title = document.createElement("div");
    youtube.className = "yo";
    youtube.innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='el'>Просмотор</a><a href='#' class='el1'>Добавить</a><img style='width: 130px;height: 90px' src='" + ImgYuoTube + "'>";
    youtube.setAttribute("youtub_clip", i);
    title.innerText = "Не понятное название ";
    title.className = "yo1";
    app.appendChild(youtube);
    youtube.appendChild(title);
    youtube.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log("ТЕСТ", i);
    });
  }

}
```

```css
.yo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.yo1 {
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  outline-width: 10px;
}
a {
  display: none;
}
.el {
  position: absolute;
  color: deepskyblue;
  left: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.el1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: deepskyblue;
  left: 30px;
  top: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.yo:hover a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="elbed"></div>
<div class="app">
```

Comment: А пагинацию как лучше сделать? Через CSS или по обращению к базе? Там будет больше 10 тыс. таких элементов.